# Window 10 High Ram after 30 min usage

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have very different problem. I start window 10 with ~21% ram usage (No other application open). Now I start using my normal laptop which include chrome + chatting (WhatsApp, slack, team) etc. after 30 mints. Ram is like ~70% usage i closed all application then ram ~46%. I don't know why its double after closing everything.

**Second issue**: When ram goes up to ~80% then window start suspending my process which cause application stop running.

Please suggest me solution for both problems. I don't know its due to any program or window own problem. I don't want to install window again.

```
Device name Legion5
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.9 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
```

Comment: Main thing is window stop working after 80% usage of ram.

Comment: Start Resource Monitor, sort the Memory section by "Working Set" and wait for the problem to happen. Which process is the top user of memory and how much?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Task Manager’s memory information. You need to go to the _Performance_ tab, then _Memory_. If you do not see tabs, press _More details_ at the bottom first.

Comment: Look for a legacy or non-compliant app or a virus.

Comment: Have you disabled Windows page file or set it to a very small size? What processes consume the RAM?